# Canvas same size as parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a nice HTML layout with a left bar, right bar and centre area.  The left bar has a top and bottom label for text and (when uncommented) a vertically central canvas.  The layout does actually resize itself nicely when the browser window size changes.

When I uncomment the canvas and try to fit it to the parent size using JavaScript handling the resize message, it somehow prevents the layout from sizing itself according to the window extents.  Instead the window gains a vertical scrollbar and the layout is no longer "100%" but more than the viewport size.

The code in question looks something like this:

```
<tr style="height: 80%;">
    <td align="center" id="controlparent" bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
        <canvas id="control" width="100%" height="100%" class="slider" style="background-color:blue"></canvas>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What mistake did I make?

(Please note I'm now doing the layout with an HTML table - I've tried CSS for layout and it's too painful for words to a beginner).

[Here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RobinsonUK/3ofw22m3/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canvas `width` and `height` attributes (and properties) are always given as pixels without any units.

If you don't want to use CSS, in which case you would use the `style="width:100%;height:100%"` attribute inside the element, you would need to calculate the width/height of parent using JavaScript.

To calculate parent size using JavaScript:

```js
var ctrl = document.getElementById("control"),
    parentSize = ctrl.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect();

ctrl.width  = parentSize.width;
ctrl.height = parentSize.height;
```

```css
html, body {width:100%; height:100%; margin:0}
```

```html
<tr style="height: 80%;">
  <td align="center" id="controlparent" bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
    <canvas id="control" width="100%" height="100%" class="slider" style="background-color:blue"></canvas>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Ah, you're right it worked when I used style instead of the HTML property.  Thank you K3N.  Please edit your response back.

Comment: @Robinson just remember that default size of the canvas *bitmap* will be 300x150 so you might want to set size for this as well (added one approach to the answer on how this can be calculated)

Comment: Actually I spoke too soon.  Although I can set the canvas size, it seems to affect the overall height of the table thereafter, so I end up with the bottom label going out of the window and a scrollbar appearing.  It doesn't seem to matter how I calculate it or whether I use CSS height 100%.

Comment: @Robinson I vaguely think I recall some issues with height using tables. If possible you could consider using divs with table layout http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table or flex http://caniuse.com/#search=flex (then I see you want to avoid this - on the other hand, tables aren't really meant for layout so it can prove to be more painful than diving into CSS which you will need at some point anyways.. just my opinion :) ).

Comment: Layout with CSS is incomprehensible to me.  I tried but it was so fragile I just can't go with it.

Comment: Again it works.  I see what I did wrong.  Your original idea to use 100% with the style rather than the attribute was correct.  Thanks.